# Can GLSL handle buffers with arbitrary length?

Tags: opengl, svg, glsl

I have an art application I'm dabbling with that uses OpenGL for accelerated graphics rendering.  I'd like to be able to add the ability to draw arbitrary piecewise curves - pretty much the same sort of shapes that can be defined by the SVG 'path' element.

Rather than tessellating my paths into polygons on the CPU, I thought it might be better to pass an array of values in a buffer to my shader defining the pieces of my curve and then using an in/out test to check which pixels were actually inside.  In other words, I'd be iterating through a potentially large array of data describing each segment in my path.

From what I remember back when I learned shader programming years ago, GPUs handle if statements by evaluating both branches and then throwing away the branch that wasn't used.  This would effectively mean that it would end up silently running through my entire buffer even if I only used a small part of it (i.e., my buffer has the capacity to handle 1024 curve segments, but the simple rectangle I'm drawing only uses the first four of them).

How do I write my code to deal with this variable data?  Can modern GPUs handle conditional code like this well?

Comment: Moderns GPUs are usually handling `if` correctly. However, mobile GPUs often dont and run both branches.

Answer (score 0):

GPUs can handle arbitrary-length buffers and conditionals (or fake it convincingly). The problem is that a vertex and geometry shaders cannot generate arbitrary number of triangles from a short description.

OpenGL 4.0 added two new types of shaders: Tessellation Control shaders and Tessellation Evaluation shaders. These shaders give you the ability to tessellate curves and surfaces on the GPU.

I found [this tutorial](https://computeranimations.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/rasterization-of-parametric-curves-using-tessellation-shaders-in-glsl/) to be quite useful in showing how to tessellate Bezier curves on the GPU.